# Maximum distance to hit a moving a target

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I was given the following version of the "Monkey and the Hunter" problem:

A monkey is hanging from a tree at a height H. A hunter aims directly at the monkey (point object) from an horizontal distance d. At the moment in which the rifle is fired, the monkey skillfully drops from the tree. 
a) Does the monkey survive? 
b) Suppose that d is very large. Does the solution found in a) make sense? 
c) Calculate the limit value of d so a) makes sense.

My problem is with the question c), because I was told to write the distance d in function of H and g, but I can't eliminate the velocity of the bullet from my equations.
The limit case is when the bullet and the monkey get at the same moment to the floor.

The equations of motion are:

Bullet: $$ x(t)=v_0 cos( \theta )t \;\;\; y(t)=v_0sin(\theta)t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$ 
Monkey: $$ x(t)=d \;\;\; y(t)=H-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$

Their respective fall times are:

$$ t_{Monkey \; y=0}= \sqrt{\frac{2H}{g}} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;t_{Bullet \; y=0}=\frac{2 v_0 sin( \theta)}{g}$$ 
And we know that $$ t_{Monkey \; y=0}=t_{Bullet \; y=0} $$

Their positions must be equal, so we get:
$$ v_0 cos(\theta)t_{y=0}=d $$
$$ v_0sin(\theta)t_{y=0}=H $$

Isolating d: 
$$ d=\sqrt{\frac{2Hv_0^2}{g}-H^2} $$

If I think about the situation described in the problem, I can't see how this case is independent of velocity. Does anyone have any idea of how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct, this formula must be dependent on $v$.

The range is essentially limited by the falling time - if the bullet and monkey hit the ground before the bullet hits the monkey, they will not collide.

If the bullet leaves the gun at a very high speed, it will close the distance to the monkey very quickly, allowing $d$ to be very large for your fixed limit on falling time. If the bullet leaves the gun slowly, the monkey will fall farther before the bullet reaches him, possibly hitting the ground before getting shot. If the gun has a low muzzle velocity, the monkey needs to be closer.

You could imagine an infinite-speed bullet that travels in a straight line (almost like a laser), which would allow you to shoot a monkey arbitrarily far away.